# What can be done if "I" sent a new job application email to my current HR (where I am working) due to typo error?

Tags: job-search, new-job, human-resources, email

Detail: My brother was operating my personal email, from there he sent a new job application to the wrong address; I genuinely did not want to apply for the new job, in fact I had just received a raise at my present job.

This is a partly India govt. owned company (kind of subsidiary of public sector unit) where I work. The email has my resume with name of the "prospect" company. No negative things about my employer.

Due to a typing error in the "to" field and the email has landed into the email folder of my current HR. There is no option to recall the message.

I have sent another email on discovering the error, this time addressing my own company HR directly, stating the above facts.

- Should I personally contact HR and reiterate the facts? What else should be done to control the damage that can be caused?
- Should I be prepared for my boss to be asking me on this?
- Should I indeed start looking for a new job asap, when it was not
  my strong intention earlier (I mean who is not open for a better opportunity, but I had specifically no desire for this "new" job)

Clarification: My brother applied "on my behalf". He does that sometimes, at times without my permission but there has never been such a major miss before. Usually, I can ignore what he does, because at max, even if invited for interview, I can say I'm not interested in the exact role.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I really was looking forward to replies from this community and you. Definitely going to follow all your suggestions. I've updated the question a bit, can you please have a re look?

Comment: Are you and your brother in the same field and industry? Is it what he is applying to (and by mistake sent to your HR), exact same position to your skill set? If no, then you are not in a big problem ..

Comment: I'm confused by what happened. Your *brother* was on your computer. He used your email address to send *your* resume to a prospective employer (who happens to be your current employer)? I could, maybe, understand letting your brother use your laptop. But it would be simple for him to get his own email account. And I seriously don't understand why he was emailing *your* resume to anyone.

Comment: To add to what Dwizum said, why does _your_ resume have the name of the prospect company? Why is your brother editing your resume in the first place? Is he looking for a Job for you?

Comment: Added a clarification: Brother was applying on my behalf

Comment: Your clarification really changes things. The fact that your brother supposedly sent _your_ resume from _your_ account sounds extremely fishy. Really, the best angle you've got is telling them that your brother played a prank on you while you left your email program open (and that you've learned your lesson and will never do that again). Yes, it's a lie but still more believable than that he would apply on your behalf and you wouldn't know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much else that you can do.  You have already contacted HR and explained the situation, what they do with this information is out of your control.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've updated "what to do" question, can you please have a re look. Every bit of sound advice will help me a lot.

Comment: @DSR Joe Strazzere's comment is the best advice. Prevent future occurrences by denying your brother access to your personal email account. It would be a lot easier to explain this away if it came from his account instead of yours